# Sap scrip 3 as 1

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me how to make 3 VBA as 1 VBA . After  export Data Range C.xlsx done Next…

The next problem is how to make the name of the export data with value in the column:

```
A1 = Export Data Range C.xlsx

A2 = Export Data Range D.xlsx

A3= Export Data Range E.xlsx
```

Below the vba code

```
Sub ExportC()

If Not IsObject(Application1) Then
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Application1 = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
Set Connection = Application1.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If '

   
   Dim LastRow
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   
   Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
   
   LastRow = sht.Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
   sht.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the quickest way in this case for you is just to write a Sub `Main` and call the three other subs you've already got.

```
Sub Main()
   ExportC
   ExportD
   ExportE
End Sub
```

For the other question, just replace `session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "Export Data Range C.xlsx"` with `session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Range("A1").value` in `ExportC` and in the other subs correspondingly. You might need to add a reference to the sheet where the values are on like `sht.Range(A1").value` if `sht` ist the sheet in question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Next Range:

after sub export C done the vba check the

LastRow = sht.Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
sht.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy

After sub export D done the vba check

LastRow = sht.Range("E2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
sht.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Copy

and so on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).